# Getting error: coverage.exceptions.ConfigError: File pattern can't include '**/**' while generating coverage for python project

Tags: python, jenkins, continuous-integration, pytest, coverage.py

I am trying to generate code coverage for a python project. I am running the command:

```
pytest --cov-config=./coveragerc --cov-report html:target/coverage --cov=./
```

This command should help me generate an html based coverage report, but I am getting the error:

```
+ pytest --cov-config=./coveragerc --cov-report html:target/coverage --cov=./
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/bin/pytest", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(console_main())
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 190, in console_main
    code = main()
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 148, in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 329, in _prepareconfig
    config = pluginmanager.hook.pytest_cmdline_parse(
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 55, in _multicall
    gen.send(outcome)
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/helpconfig.py", line 103, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config: Config = outcome.get_result()
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_result.py", line 60, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1058, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1346, in parse
    self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 1248, in _preparse
    self.hook.pytest_load_initial_conftests(
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
    return outcome.get_result()
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_result.py", line 60, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest_cov/plugin.py", line 152, in pytest_load_initial_conftests
    plugin = CovPlugin(options, early_config.pluginmanager)
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest_cov/plugin.py", line 203, in __init__
    self.start(engine.Central)
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest_cov/plugin.py", line 225, in start
    self.cov_controller.start()
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest_cov/engine.py", line 44, in ensure_topdir_wrapper
    return meth(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest_cov/engine.py", line 234, in start
    self.cov.start()
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/control.py", line 603, in start
    self._init_for_start()
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/control.py", line 557, in _init_for_start
    self._inorout.configure(self.config)
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/inorout.py", line 267, in configure
    self.omit_match = GlobMatcher(self.omit, "omit")
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/files.py", line 288, in __init__
    self.re = globs_to_regex(self.pats, case_insensitive=env.WINDOWS)
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/files.py", line 372, in globs_to_regex
    rx = join_regex(map(_glob_to_regex, patterns))
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/misc.py", line 185, in join_regex
    regexes = list(regexes)
  File "/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/change_dx-airflow_cd-flow_PR-106/.pyenv-home-jenkins-.pyenv-shims-python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/coverage/files.py", line 345, in _glob_to_regex
    raise ConfigError(f"File pattern can't include {m[0]!r}")
coverage.exceptions.ConfigError: File pattern can't include '**/**'
```

This is my `coveragerc` file:

```
[run]
omit =
    test/*
    **/**site-packages**/**
    **__init__.py
```

I am unable to figure out the reason of the failure. We have been using this coveragerc for a while now and everything used to work fine. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for the [last release](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html) on December 18.
Changed file pattern matching.

File path patterns are used for include and omit, and for combining path remapping. They follow common shell syntax:

`* matches any number of file name characters, not including the directory separator.`

`? matches a single file name character.`

`** matches any number of nested directory names, including none.`

`Both / and \ will match either a slash or a backslash, to make cross-platform matching easier.`

I think the configuration you are looking for is the following:

```
[run]
omit =
    test/**
    */*site-packages*/**
    *__init__.py
```